# Compare ratios of dispositions and combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given $x,y,n\in\mathbb{N}^+$, and $x<y$, which quantity among

> $$
> u=\frac{x^n}{y^n}\,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,v=\frac{\binom{x+n-1}{n}}{\binom{y+n-1}{n}}
> $$

is greater?

This is probably a trivial question (sorry, in case), but I have troubles to discuss it rigorously. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a sketch:

- The left hand side is $$\frac x y \qquad\times\qquad \frac x y \qquad\times \cdots \times \quad\frac x y \quad\times \quad\frac x y$$
- The right hand side is $$\frac{x+n-1}{y+n-1} \times \frac{x+n-2}{y+n-2} \times \cdots \times \frac{x+1}{y+1} \times \quad\frac x y\,\,$$
- When $0 \le x \lt y$,  the terms on the left hand side are smaller than the corresponding terms on the right hand side, apart for the last terms which are equal
- So the left hand side is smaller than the right hand side when $n\gt 1$

Comment: Great answer! Very beautiful way of seeing it! Thanks a lot Henry!