# Comparing combinations with repetitions

Tags: combinatorics

Given $x,y,n\in\mathbb{N}^+$, and $x<y$, which quantity among

> $$
> p=\frac{\binom{x+n-1}{n}}{\binom{y+n-1}{n}}\,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,q=\frac{\binom{n+1}{n-1}}{\binom{n+2}{n}}
> $$

is greater?

I tried to use the technique presented in this post [Compare ratios of dispositions and combinations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2840371/559615), but without success.

I apologize in case it is a trivial question. Thanks however for your help!

Comment: The right hand side equals ${{n+1}\choose2}\big/{{n+2}\choose2}=\frac n{n+2}$. Perhaps this makes it easier?

Comment: Thanks Steve! Yes, I worked this out, but then I failed to compare $n/(n+2)$ with $p$. I tried not to simplify (as in the Answer of the quoted post), but in this case I get completely lost...

Comment: Computations suggest it depends on $x$,$y$, and $n$. For example, if $n=2$, $p<q$ in some cases ($x$ small or much less than $y$) but $p\ge q$ sometimes. When $n=2, x=7,y=10$, $p\ge q$, but when $n=2, x=7,y>10$, $p<q$. It’s not hard to calculate many examples and maybe you can come up with a conjecture.

Comment: I see. Thanks for this!